# React Native - Multi-select convert Class Component to Functional Component

Tags: javascript, react-native, multi-select

I am new at using React Hooks and I need to convert my `Class Components` code to `Functional Hooks`. I have the `Class Components` logic below that works well. However the above code is giving me issues. I am trying to create a multiple select list. Can anyone please assist with fixing this code.

```
    const { data, status } = useQuery('stores', fetchStores)
    const [isSelected, setIsSelected] = useState(false)

    const storeList = data

    useEffect(() => {

        let array = storeList.map((item, index) => {
            isSelected = false
            return { ...item }
        })

        setIsSelected({ ...isSelected, array: { ...storeList.array } })

        selectHandler()

    }, [])


    const selectHandler = (ind) => {

        let array = storeList.map((item, index) => {
            if (ind == index) {
                item.isSelected = !item.isSelected
            }
            return { ...item }
        })
        setIsSelected({ ...isSelected, array: { ...storeList.array } })
    }
```

The Same Logic with `ComponentDidMount` works perfectly

```
async componentDidMount() {

        let array = this.state.storeList.map((item, index) => {
            this.isSelected = false
            return { ...item }
        })
        this.setState({ storeList: array })
    }

    selectionHandler = (ind) => {
        const { storeList } = this.state
        let array = storeList.map((item, index) => {
            if (ind == index) {
                item.isSelected = !item.isSelected
            }
            return { ...item }
        })
        this.setState({ storeList: array })
    }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Thanks @roshnet I get storeList undefined when I console log it and this error...
`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'storeList'.map)`

Comment: @roshnet and `array` is also undefined when I set it to `SetIsSelected`